# multiple ssl certificate for one domain/subdomain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain

To begin let's say I have this configuration :

mywebsite.com is related on machine 0.0.0.1 (with ssl certificate)

cloud.mywebsite.com is related on machine 0.0.0.2 (without ssl certificate)

can I ask for a new SSL certificate for "cloud.mywebsite.com" or this will create issues because of domain/subdomain ?

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking for a new SSL Certificate, you only need to get Wildcard SSL Certificate that will secure your main domain as well as its all sub-domains. For example:

If you get Wildcard SSL certificate for ***mywebsite.com** then it will secure,

- https://cloud.mywebite.com
- https://mail.mywebsite.com
- https://photos.mywebsite.com
- https://anything.mywebsite.com

So, you will not have to manage multiple SSL certificates for your main domain and its sub-domain. Wildcard SSL certificate will reduce the hassle of server administrators for multiple SSL management. I suggest you to read [this article](https://www.cheapsslshop.com/blog/wildcard-ssl-bonding-of-lowest-cost-and-strong-security), which will give you clear understanding of Wildcard SSL Certificate.

Comment: My goal is to use free certificates provided by Let's Encrypt which is implemented with automatic renewal on my website provider & on Synology. This is why I ask if it might be a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, Let’s encrypt is not offering Wildcard Certificate.

Comment: I know, Let's Encrypt provide free SSL certificate, it's not bad ! 
So, asking for 2 distinct certificates in this configuration (one certificate for mywebsite.com and another for cloud.mywebsite.com) will work ?